# Having issue in installation of nodemom node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nodemon

C:\Users\shankar\first-app>npm install nodemom
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: nodemom@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\shankar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-08-06T06_37_40_602Z-debug.log

Comment: nodemom???  `npm i nodemon`

Answer (score 4):

Sir, you are using wrong command its nodemon not nodemom